# ASP.NET - App_Code - Mix VB and C# in the same folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

[image]

I use WebForms type. and in my website project, there are pages which are using VB and also C#...
      It works!...

But the problem is, as you can see on the picture above, I put 'cs' file and 'vb' file in 'App_Code' folder, and there are Error appear.....

> The files '/App_Code/BSN3.Class.cs' and '/App_Code/AssemblyInfo.vb'
>   use a different language, which is not allowed since they need to be
>   compiled together.

Comment: If you deploy, it will work. So don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok... I already solved the problem..

in Web.Config file, add code

```
<compilation debug="false">
    <codeSubDirectories>
        <add directoryName="VBCode" />
        <add directoryName="CSCode" />
    </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

And just seperate VB and CS code into two folder which are 'VBCode' and 'CSCode' ..

so, it will look like this

[image]

Comment: Note: It works, but you can't call C# code from VB and vice versa.